# How do you use a copy constructor to copy over constant variables?

Tags: c++

My class has the following private variables, including a const static one, as you can see:

```
private:
    // class constant for # of bits in an unsigned short int:
    const static int _USI_BITS = sizeof(usi)*CHAR_BIT; 
    usi* _booArr;  
    int _booArrLen;
    int _numBoos;
```

I'm new to using copy constructors and I can't figure out how to write one. Here's my attempt:

```
BitPack::BitPack(const BitPack& other) { 
    _USI_BITS = other._USI_BITS;
    _booArr = new usi[other._booArrLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < _booArrLen; ++i)  
        _booArr[i] = other._booArr[i];
    _booArrLen = other._booArrLen;
    _numBoos = other.numBoos; 
}
```

The compiler says:

**error: assignment of read-only variable 'BitPack::_USI_BITS'**

Please disabuse me of my foolish ways.

Comment: Is the `const` bit a give away. It is constant!

Comment: All `BitPack` instances shares the same _static_ data member `_USI_BITS`. Thus, are you sure you want to copy it across instances?

Comment: `_USI_BITS` is `const` but you're attempting to change it. Maybe it should be neither `static` nor `const` in the first place if it relys on instantiations of the class.

Comment: Ok, so does C++ by default initialize _USI_BITS on the copied-to variable?

Comment: @user2967799 It's static.  There is only one copy of it, no matter how many instances you have.  You don't need to copy it.  Take that line out.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. My bad. Can you guys show me how to make the assignment operator?

Answer (score 1):

Constructors, including the copy constructors, need to set *instance members*, i.e. the ones that are not `static`. Static members are shared by all instances, and therefore must be initialized outside of any constructors.

In your case, you need to remove the

```
_USI_BITS = other._USI_BITS;
```

line: the two sides refer to the same `static` member, so the assignment has no effect.

The rest of your copy constructor is fine. Note that since your copy constructor allocates resources, the [*rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) suggests that you should add a custom assignment operator, and a custom destructor:

```
BitPack& operator=(const BitPack& other) {
    ...
}
~BitPack() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how to make the assignment operator? I know there's some nuance about using the swap algorithm or something.

Comment: @user2967799 Assignment is similar to copy constructor, except you cannot assume that the current object is empty. In your specific case it means that you would call `delete [] _booArr` before assigning it a new array. The rest of the code would be identical to that of your copy constructor.